# Web.Api 2 and Asp.Net core in one solution

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-web-api2

Currently we use ASP.NET core project for our UI. There is need to add an OData service to it. As far as I understand it is not supported well enough yet, so it was decided to implement it in a separate Web.Api 2 project.

- Is there someone who has such an experience?
- Is it a way to go?
- May I encounter troubles with deployment to Azure?

Any ideas and thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you hosted the web site on a different web application, then you have to enable CORS on the web API, and you have to test it during development to avoid any issues.

You can overcome this issue by deploying both the UI and API to the same Azure Web App. you can have the UI under the root and the API under a virtual directory, ex: apis

Comment: I believe the second half of your answer is what I am looking for.  Can you provide some instruction on how to accomplish this?  When I try to deploy the second application (API) to the same Azure App, the first application (Web / UI) is overwritten and vice versa.